# How to post request an authorize code OneDrive

Tags: c#, windows-7, client, onedrive, live-sdk

```
 Uri url = new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf");

        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["client_id"] = "000000004012B29D";
            data["scope"] = "wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.offline_access";
            data["response_type"] = "code";
            data["redirect_uri"] = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";       

            var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);


        }
```

I most likely think my post-request is wrong, but don't know why, only thing I have doubts with is my adding with the scopes, %20 is a simple space, I am not sure whether i can write it like this.
I should be supposed to receive a resulturl? But all i get is this html code:

```
"<!-- ServerInfo: BAYIDSLGN3A089 2014.10.28.00.06.35 Live1 ExclusiveNew LocVer:0 -->\r\n<!-- PreprocessInfo: BTSA007:RR1BLDA080,  -- Version: 16,0,25347,0 -->\r\n<html dir=\"ltr\">\r\n    <head>\r\n        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n        <base href=\"https://login.live.com/pp1600/\"/>\r\n        \r\n         \r\n             \t\r\n                 \r\n                                            \r\n                                    \t\t\r\n                            <title>Microsoft account</title>\r\n        <meta name=\"PageID\" content=\"i4400\">\r\n        <meta name=\"SiteID\" content=\"38936\">\r\n        <meta name=\"ReqLC\" content=\"1033\">\r\n        <meta name=\"LocLC\" content=\" \">\r\n        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"CSS/WEBblue1033.css?x=16.0.25000.0\"/>\r\n        <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n            function EndPPCRL(rs, u) \r\n            {\r\n                if (external) \r\n                {\r\n                    try \r\n                    {\r\n                        if (rs) \r\n                        {\r\n                            external.RequestStatus = rs;\r\n                            external.WebFlowUrl = u;\r\n                            external.NotifyIdentityChanged();\r\n                            external.ReturnToApp();\r\n                        }\r\n                        else \r\n                        {\r\n                            external._b7(); external.BrowseToAuthUI();\r\n                        }\r\n                    } \r\n                    catch (e) { }\r\n                }\r\n            } \r\n            function BodyLoad() \r\n            { \r\n                EndPPCRL(-2147186656); \r\n            }\r\n        </script>\r\n        <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n            WizardExternalHelper = function(){ };\r\n            WizardExternalHelper.prototype =\r\n            {\r\n                setProperty: function(key, value) \r\n                { \r\n                    try\r\n                    { \r\n                        window.external.Property(key) = value;\r\n                    }\r\n                    catch (e) { }\r\n                },\r\n                finalNext: function()\r\n                { \r\n                    try\r\n                    { \r\n                        window.external.FinalNext();\r\n                    }\r\n                    catch (e) { }\r\n                }\r\n            };\r\n        </script>\r\n                <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n            try \r\n            {\r\n                var externalHelper = new WizardExternalHelper();\r\n                externalHelper.setProperty(\"ExtendedErrorString\", \"\");\r\n                externalHelper.setProperty(\"ErrorCode\", parseInt(1));\r\n                externalHelper.setProperty(\"ErrorString\", \"This service isn't available right now—please try again later.\");\r\n                externalHelper.finalNext();\r\n            } catch (e) {};\r\n            function OnBack() {}; \r\n            function OnNext() {};\r\n        </script>\r\n    </head>\r\n    <body class=\"modern\" onLoad=\"BodyLoad()\">\r\n      <div class=\"header\" id=\"idHeaderTD9\">\r\n        <span>Microsoft account</span>\r\n      </div>\r\n      <div class=\"content\">\r\n         \r\n             \t\r\n                 \r\n                                            <div style=\"padding:15px 0 0 0;font-size:1px;\">&nbsp;</div>\r\n                        <h1 class=\"css0046\">We're unable to complete your request</h1>\r\n                        <p class=\"css0005\">Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.</p>\r\n                                    \t\t\r\n                          </div>\r\n    </body>\r\n</html>\r\n<!-- _h-Agent: -->\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't POST request to get the first code (which looks to be what you're doing). The flow looks like this:

- Send the user to the authorize page, they authorize your app and get redirected to your application with a `code` GET parameter
- You take that code and POST it with a bunch of other stuff to Microsoft. They respond with a bunch of OAuth tokens.
- You can now make requests with those tokens.

The docs are pretty bad but have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx

To summarize (these are examples from the documentation):

- Send the user to `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=0000000603DB0F&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.contoso.com%2Fcallback.php`
- Wait for the user to be directed to `http://www.contoso.com/callback.php?code=2bd12503-7e88-bfe7-c5c7-82274a740ff`, extract the `code` parameter
- POST the `code`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `grant_type` (authorization_code) and `redirect_uri` to `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf`

If everything is fine, you'll get your token.

Comment: Isn't grant_type = "token" to receive tokens?

Comment: @HTLCloudManager no, it's definitely `authorization_code`, have a look at the examples under "Get an access token and an authentication token" in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx) :)

Comment: When I get the tokens, do I have to do something with them? Does my LiveConnectClient get updated automatically , or how do I then use the tokens, the only thing I want is to keep my LiveConnectClient "alive".
Using LiveSDK ;)